# Adding remote URL with the JGit API

Tags: jgit

Is there a way to clone from a remote URL using JGit API in which I can somewhere change the origin which it takes by default and make it as `origin2`, as at `origin` there is another remote configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CloneCommand::setRemote()` to change the remote name of the repository that is about to be cloned. By default, it is named `origin`.

You can also change the remote name after it was added by directly manipulating the Git configuration:

```java
Repository repository = ...;
String oldName = "origin";
String newName = "other-origin";
StoredConfig config = repository.getConfig();
Set<String> names = config.getNames( ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REMOTE_SECTION, oldName );
for( String name : names ) {
  String value = config.getString( ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REMOTE_SECTION, oldName, name );
  config.setString( ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REMOTE_SECTION, newName, name, value );
}
config.unsetSection( ConfigConstants.CONFIG_REMOTE_SECTION, oldName );
config.save();
```

In order to add a new remote, use the `RemoteAddCommand` like this:

```java
git.remoteAdd().setName( "new-remote" ).setUri( new URIish( "..." ) ).call();
```